# Passing data between data fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation

Hi I have made an app and trying to pass data between two fragments in an app

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/title2">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/title2"
    android:name="com.example.order10.title"
    android:label="title" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_title2_to_pageone"
        app:destination="@id/pageone" />
   </fragment>
   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/pageone"
    android:name="com.example.order10.pageone"
    android:label="pageone" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_pageone_to_finalpage"
        app:destination="@id/finalpage" >
        <argument android:defaultValue="Hi"
            android:name="text" />
    </action>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/finalpage"
    android:name="com.example.order10.finalpage"
    android:label="fragment_finalpage"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_finalpage" >
    <argument
        android:name="order_text"
        app:argType="string"
        android:defaultValue="Hi" />
  </fragment>
   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:name="com.example.order10.about"
    android:label="Order 1.0" />
 </navigation>
```

**Code for passing data**

```
fun navigation(text:String){
    var args= bundleOf()
    args.putString("order_text",text)
    view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_pageone_to_finalpage,args)


}      navigation("This is order one ")
```

**Code for receiving data**

```
 val order_text:TextView?=view?.findViewById(R.id.order_text)
    order_text?.text=arguments?.getString("order_text")
```

But the it doesn't work it doesn't even show the  default text, I have applied all plugins and dependencies

Comment: Can you show code, when you clicked?

Comment: The below answers are not working can someone please provide with a better approach

Comment: Please share your error or explain more!!

Comment: Hey see I am applying both answers below but when I am running only I am navigating, even default text is not shown. If you don't mind could you please a two screen app where data is passed from fragment 1 to fragment 2 and upload it some where like GitHub so that I can compare it. By the way there is no compliation error

Comment: @AshutoshPanda , I update my answer , use it

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code for passing data `change` to this :**

```
fun navigation(text:String){

    val args = bundleOf("order_text" to text)
    view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_pageone_to_finalpage,args)
}
```

**Code for receiving data `change` to this :**

```
val receiveData = arguments?.getString("order_text")!!

val order_text:TextView?=view?.findViewById(R.id.order_text)
    order_text?.text=receiveData
```

---

**Update :**

Change your `finalPage` to this :

```
class finalpage : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finalpage, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val receiveData = arguments?.getString("order_text")!!
        val order_text:TextView?=view.findViewById(R.id.order_text)
        order_text?.text=receiveData
    }
}
```

**YOU CAN USE COMPONENTS AFTER THAT YOU DEFINE YOUR VIEW**

Comment: Hey see I am applying both answers below but when I am running only I am navigating, even default text is not shown. If you don't mind could you please a two screen app where data is passed from fragment 1 to fragment 2 and upload it some where like GitHub so that I can compare it. By the way there is no compliation error

Comment: @AshutoshPanda, You dont apply my answer! , but you should debug your app my code is ok i am sure , i think you get data in fragment 2 and you cant show it in textView maybe your text color in textView is same as background color,please share your xml codes

Comment: See I have checked there is no problem in text color it is just showing textview.

Comment: @AshutoshPanda,push your project in github and URL for me

Comment: Download the zip file and again there is a zip file extract it and open in android studio

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer could you please explain the answer I am still learning app development.

Comment: @AshutoshPanda , If its useful please accept and vote up , at first you should create your view in onCreate() then you can use your component like : editText,textView,buttons and ...

Comment: Hey when I want to ask that what was the fault in previous answer because same answer was given in android documentation

Answer (score 1):

**For passing data :**

```
val direction = pageoneDirections.actionPageOneToFinalPage("your text")
view?.findNavController()?.navigate(direction)
```

**For receiving data :**

In your class :

```
val args: finalpageArgs by navArgs()
```

In your onCreateView :

```
val order_text = args.order_text
```